# Hill walking and camping in the Peak District

Tags: uk, camping, walking, peak-district

I would like to do a moderate hill walking (5-6 hours) in the [Peak District](http://www.peakdistrict.gov.uk/), and camp as well. Which part(s) is suitable, for this activity?

Comment: You should try asking this on http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

I usually visit Peak District for rock climbing, so I can't offer any ready-made itineraries for walking. If I were to plan a walk myself though I would start from looking at a good map, and the Ordnance Survey Explorer series is usually the best, see:
https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/shop/explorer-map-the-peak-district-white-peak-area.html and
https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/shop/explorer-map-the-peak-district-dark-peak-area.html
(I recommend the Dark Area). These maps include marked trails, pubs and campsites.

Luckily Bing has Ordnance Survey maps, so you can start from there, e.g. http://binged.it/1tkAPFe

As a side note, in busy periods (summer, nice weekends) I strongly recommend calling the campsite first and making sure they will have a place.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Edale](http://binged.it/1vc9Ywf). There are several campsites in the valley, and some great walking in all directions.   These campsites are also a short walk from the train station.

Comment: Been there pretty sweet ;-)